# Arrow Keys Disable Touchpad/Mapped To Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, bug-reporting, elementary

This randomly started happening. Left, Right, Up and Down arrow keys all make a "touchpad disabled" notification icon appear, as well as open a Music player. I went into Settings >> Keyboard and no such shortcuts exist.

This has happened to me once before and it seems as though none of the threads (very few available) have the solution I'm looking for.

FN + Arrow Key (any) still do their task. Volume and Brigthness. Without FN, I cannot normally do anything without apps opening and my touchpad disabling. The funny thing is it doesn't even actually disable, it just keeps saying it is. Unless I hit FN + Touchpad icon, it doesn't actually disable, it just tells me it's disabled for some weird reason.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem on my Acer desktop. It is actually a hardware static energy issue.

I solved my problem by shutting down the PC. I unplugged the CPU power cable and pressed the power button for 10 sec. After restart it worked fine.

If you're using a laptop it may be required to remove the battery and power adapter cord and than press the power button!

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the device.
I held down the power button to force-shutdown, and after boot-up, it's working fine.

Comment: It’s rarely a good option to force a shutdown.

Comment: So, should i have done a usual shutdown and boot-up?

Comment: yes. When you shut down normally the os will complete its processes in an orderly way … forcing a shutdown prevents those processes completing. I don’t think forcing a shutdown by holding down the power button has any advantages over a proper software initiated shutdown (unless the os has irretrievably crashed to the point of being unable to shut it down).

Comment: ohh, Thankyou  bruh!